# A word instead of "as normal"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice

> If we think of a world in which a remote control does not get lost
>   **as normal**, when it disappears we get angry (Botton, 2000).

Here I am looking for a word instead of *as normal*, maybe more than one word. I think it can be understood what I meant by *as normal*. Could you help out?

Comment: You can make this idiomatic with a plain old adverb: something like "does not normally/ordinarily get lost".

Comment: "as normal" refers to "a world" there.

Comment: But you make that entirely clear with "a world in which. . . "; what more do you need?

Comment: OK, I understood what you mean, now I am checking the dictionary :)

Comment: Aha - looking at Rathony's answer I see that it is probably I who misunderstood. If Rathony has got the right handle on what you're trying to say, I'd abandon the *think of X as Y* construction and go for something like "If we think that in a normal world our remote control never gets lost, then we get angry when it disappears".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If we think of a world in which a remote control does not get lost ***as
>   normal***, when it disappears we get angry.

The above sentence has a "think of X as Y" construction. If you place "as Y" that far from "think of X", it might cause a confusion.

I advise you to rephrase it to:

> If we think of a world ***as normal*** in which a remote control does
>   not get lost, when it disappears we get angry.

You could consider using "[***ordinary***](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/ordinary)" in place of "normal" as suggested in the comment as it means:

> With no special or distinctive features; normal: ‘he sets out to
>   depict ordinary people’ ‘it was just an ordinary evening’

There are many other words that can replace it. Visit [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/normal).